# Is there a code/function that solves an equation for either X or Y?

Tags: r, quadratic

I have a simple quadratic equation, but I need to find a way for R to solve for X or Y depending on the value I input for either. For example, my equation is

```
y = 232352x^2+2468776x+381622
```

I need to find a code that solves for y when x = 8000 and solve for x when y = 4000. Does such a code/function exist in R or do I have to do it manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first part (solving for y when x=8000) is pretty straightforward.

You just type:

```
232352 * 8000^2 + 2468776 * 8000 + 381622
```

and R gives:

```
[1] 1.489028e+13
```

The second problem involves roots. The polyroot() function is what you're after. It takes in the coefficients of the equation as a vector, and returns the roots. So for your case:

```
 polyroot(c(381622-4000,2468776,232352))
```

gives:

```
 [1]  -0.155227+0i -10.469928-0i
```

And then it's up to you to figure out which solution you want.

Remember in general if you want to solve y = Ax^2 + Bx + C for a particular value of y, you have to rearrange the equation to Ax^2 + Bx + (C-y) = 0. 
Translated to R code this is:

```
coeff <- c(C-y,B,A)
polyroot(coeff)
```

Where you substitute A,B,C,y with the relevant numbers.